# iPhone application to "wake up" at a certain time

Tags: iphone, sdk

Is it possible for an iPhone app to stay dormant while making some kind of regitration request with the iPhone OS so that it will get "wake up call" at a certain time and become the active app?

Comment: It's time to start developing for Android :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would be running as a daemon...
Apple does not allow it, but the Open Toolchain certainly will give you the option to do so.

~ Natanavra.

Comment: I didn't think it necessarily means a daemon which I know is 'forbidden'.  In other words, if I want to publish in the AppStore then forget it?

Comment: @jkally - i don't know how the app store is related at all to your request.  You want to run something on the device while it's sleeping so that it can wake up at a certain time and take an action.  Then you mention the app store.  Explain how you got there.

Comment: It means two things:
1) Forget about the Appstore.
2) Forget about using the official SDK to achieve this.

As someone mentions, the best you're gonna get is Push-Notifications, and that from my personal experience isn't worth too much.

Answer (score 1):

The closest you could come (without jailbreaking) is to use Apple's [Push Notification Service](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Introduction/Introduction.html).

Comment: Ftrom what I know Push Notification Service requires the user to manually start the app upon receiving some sound alert.
This is not what I mean.

Comment: Your URL is no longer valid (404). Here is the current URL: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html